# Warning: file_put_contents(): Filename cannot be empty

Tags: 9

After updating Drupal 8 to Drupal 9, the following error is displayed on the website page:

> Warning: file_put_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in /var/www/html/web/modules/contrib/devel/src/DevelDumperManager.php on line 108

Although it is not in the logs. But there is a similar one:

> Warning: file_put_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in Drupal\search_api_solr_devel\Logging\SolariumRequestLogger->preExecuteRequest() (line 148 of /var/www/html/web/modules/contrib/search_api_solr/modules/search_api_solr_devel/src/Logging/SolariumRequestLogger.php)

Perhaps these errors are somehow related. How I do fix these errors?

I tried debugging and this is what xdebug shows for the first error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The site missing some or all of the Devel module settings. In this case the one missing is `debug_logfile`. I think the simplest way forward would be to uninstall Devel-related modules and reinstall them so their configurations may be restored. If you are using configuration management, you could add the settings to the exported configuration then re-import them. The are in `devel.settings.yml` in the Devel module.